# Angularjs not work in socket.io response

Tags: angularjs, socket.io, sails.js

When i want change something in response socket.io it does not work, but normally works.

for example, the following code when I first blur on the username does not work, but the second time it works.

```
input#username(name="username", ng-model="username", ng-blur="usernameCheck()")
input(type="submit", ng-disabled="dSubmit", value="Register")

$scope.dSubmit = true;
$scope.usernameCheck = function() {
  socket.post('/user/usernameCheck', {username: $scope.username}, function(res) {
    if(res.success) {
      $scope.dSubmit = false;
    } else {
      $scope.dSubmit = true;
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `$scope.$apply()` at the end of your `socket.post` callback:

```
  socket.post('/user/usernameCheck', {username: $scope.username}, function(res) {
    if(res.success) {
      $scope.dSubmit = false;
    } else {
      $scope.dSubmit = true;
    }
    // Apply the scope changes and tell Angular to run the digest loop
    $scope.$apply();
  });
```

Because the scope is changing in an asynchronous method, you need to call `$scope.$apply()` to let Angular know that something has changed.